# Spring AOP for non-service Class

Tags: java, spring, cxf, aop, spring-aop

I am a beginner in Spring framework. I have implemented Spring AOP for logging method execution time. Using some examples from internet, I get it working for a Service interface as specified below. But the same code is not working if I change the **expression** to a non-service class. Have give below the CXF configuration.

```
<bean id="xbean" class="com........xServiceImpl" />

<jaxrs:server id="xServiceRS" address="/xRSService">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="xbean" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="performanceLoggingAdvice" class="com......PerformanceLoggingAdvice" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="performanceLoggingPointcut"
        expression="execution(* com.....xService.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="performanceLoggingAdvice"
        pointcut-ref="performanceLoggingPointcut" id="performanceLoggingInterceptorAdvisor" />
</aop:config>
```

i have already searched in stack overflow for the similar question but I did not get a useful and specific answer to my question. Any idea what could be the issue ? How to get it working for a non service class for example Utils.java ?

Thanks in Advance for helping me..

Comment: Does Utils.java comply to bean definitions? Does it have a constructor, getter/setters ? From the name 'Utils.java', I smell a file which has a couple of static functions. If that is the case, do you still want to create an object for the Utils class?

Comment: Hi TJ, Utils.java is very much same as xService interface. I am wondering even my xService also do not have getters, setters and constructors. My Utils.java has public methods and not static methods...

Comment: Can you post the errors? Also, can you post relevant sections of 'xService' and 'Utils' ?

Comment: xService is a Service Class exposed as a REST Service. And Utils is another Service class but that is not exposed. I want to know why it is not working for an non service class. I have tried given the class as a bean in the config xml. But still not working if I change the EXPRESSION to my non service class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring AOP advices are only applied on the instances of the classes declared as Spring beans. Make your `Util` class a Spring bean, use proper pointcuts and it should work.

You should obtain the `Util` instances only through the Spring application context in that case (by calling one of the `ApplicationContext.getBean` methods), not through a call to the constructor using `new`.